# How to solve Php date() error

Tags: php, date, date-formatting

```
print date("F d,o",strtotime("1974-12-31"));
```

print `December 31, 1975` instead of `December 31 1974` ?

Im using php version 5.2.9-2

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the [Code Sample `{}`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VYd26.png) toolbar button. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: off topic, but please note that PHP 5.2 has been unsupported for several years now and has known security issues that will not be fixed. Even PHP 5.3 is nearing end-of-life now. You should upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: thanks for the advice but  I tried  to use Php 5.3   and i found a problem when I add Delete cascade  rel between my table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'o' is the ISO year. The ISO year is based on the year the biggest part of the week belongs to. In 1974, december 31st was the tuesday of week 1 of 1975.

You probably want 'Y'.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
print date("F d,Y",strtotime("1974-12-31"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Mabey try using 'Y' insted of 'o'

date("F d,Y",strtotime("1974-12-31"));